# Change MPMusicPlayerController Queue without pause in playback

Tags: objective-c, ios, mpmusicplayercontroller

Is it possible to make changes to the MPMusicPlayerController's queue, without having the small delay that setQueueWithItemCollection makes? I have read the docs, and they state that this is normal behavior. But in the app i am developing, changes to the queue may apply very frequently. For now, i am only doing changes to the queue between songs, to not make the user notice too much. But it is still very annoying.

Could it be done in a thread or something clever?

Thanks